# React native on XCode build successful but stuck at '100% on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I tried to build my `expo` project on XCode so I ejected that and open in XCode using `xed ios`. but when I tried to build it and run it show's me that build was successful but on simulator it stuck at '100%' and wont run. also on XCode I receive this:

```
"expo-updates must be configured with a valid update URL or scope key."
```

[image]

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [expo issue](https://forums.expo.dev/t/newly-created-app-crashes-on-ios-sim/45566), the solution found is:

Sign in to your `expo` account in `expo-cli` and it will configure `expo-updates` properly when you eject. You can fix this on an already ejected project after signing in by running `expo eject --no-install`.

**Or**

Check [JWrubel](https://github.com/jwrubel) comments for the same [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11513) below.

I was able to get around this issue without doing `expo login` by editing `ios/<AppName>/Supporting/Expo.plist` and adding a key for EXUpdatesURL like so:

```
<key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
<string>https://example.com</string>
```

This causes the update check to fail, but the build to succeed. I tried setting `EXUpdatesEnabled` to `false` and `EXUpdatesCheckOnLaunch` to `NEVER`, but I didn't find those had any impact on the process.